# Salesforce Dev Org - Unable to Login - No access to mail

Tags: administration, login-errors

I, System Admin of my Salesforce Org,  am unable to login to my Dev edition on NA22 instance as I do not remember the password.

User name:  firstname@dev.com

Previous email address: oldcompany@gmail.com

New email address: newcompany@target.com

When I click on forgot password it just asks me the username and sends an email to the registered email id. However, as I moved out to my Target company, I no longer have access to my email. Any help or pointers will be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Add: Reached out to Salesforce already by dropping mail to :    info@salesforcedevs.com

Comment: 1. Security question ?

Comment: 2. Other admin ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no other users or admin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're registered as an ISV, you can log a case in the Partner Portal. Otherwise, there's nothing that support is willing to do for you. You'll have to build a new Developer Edition org from scratch, or try to convince your previous manager or someone in authority to change your email for you. Depending on the company, this may either be trivial, impossible, or somewhere between. The moral of the story is that you should never use a company email for a personal Developer Edition, because you can't ever log in to it if you lose your password and your email address.

You can read more about the [requirements](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Changing-the-System-Administrator-for-my-Salesforce-account&language=en_US&type=1) imposed by Support:

> To make the change (and preserve the security and integrity of the data in your account), **we require letter on company letterhead** with the request from a C-Level executive officer (for example, your CEO, CIO, CFO, or Business Owner).

(Original emphasis preserved.)

As far as I know, they are not willing to violate this rule for Developer Edition orgs not associated to an ISV or company.

I've lost more than one good Developer Edition org this way, as support has never been willing to "compromise" my private account, despite my name, address, and phone on the record being my personal information.

Comment: Thank You for the detailed response. Could you share if that means all the trailhead badges are also lost in this process with no access to Dev Org and mail

Comment: no not an ISV. An independent account for learning. Just for contact purpose shared the other mail, for which I no longer have access.  Will keep the moral of the story in mind for next time :)

Comment: @TheRecruit Unless you linked your Trailhead to a Facebook account so you can log in that way, I'm pretty sure you won't be able to get back to your badges, either. I suppose you could try contacting the Trailhead team, as they might have a way to move your account to a new Developer Edition for you. It'd be a shame to lose all those hours of work. Try posting a message `@trailhead` on Twitter.

Comment: Yes, just tried! Received the following response. Excerpt:
"process assumes that the learner can still login to both the ‘from’ and ‘to’ Trailhead accounts. If the learner can no longer access the ‘from’ Trailhead account (e.g. they can no longer use their previous corporate login for Salesforce), we unfortunately cannot process the merge request."
Anyway, checking with support will let you know if anything works out. have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Contact Salesforce.com support. They can change the email if needed, we can't really do that.